# overlapping text over image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a registration form if username does not exist in database then it shows an image beside my text box(thick mark image) and along with that i want to show my text that

"this user name already exist"

```
$("#usr_verify").css({ "background-image": "url('<?php echo base_url();?>images/no.png')" });
$("#usr_verify2").text("it does not exist ::");
```

these two selectors are sending my text and my image in two different spans one with id usr_verify and other with the id usr_verify2

now both the span tags are in one paragraph tag. Now my error is that the text is overlapping the image, text appears onto that image. Any idea where i have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on without looking at your markup, and perhaps a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), but here's a stab at it:

Spans are inline elements, and as such, can't be given an explicit height and width. Background images are not image blocks, that assume the space required to show the entire image, but really just fill whatever area is granted them.

Try using an `img` instead of a `span`, or try to give the span `display: inline-block` so that you can set its width and height to whatever the image requires.

Edit:

[A JsFiddle showing what I mean...](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Ukr/)

Comment: Thanks @David im just applying  display:inline-bloack;  to see how does it work

Comment: <p><span id="usr_verify2" class="verify" style="font-size:9px; display: inline-block;  "></span> 
<span id="usr_verify2" class="verify" style="font-size:9px; display:inline-block"></span></p>    

now the issue is they both are moving together like if i apply padding its being applied on both

Comment: @Aron: Might this be because both spans in the code you've posted have the ID `user_verify2`?

Comment: sorry i pasted incorrectly @David here both are having same IDs but in actually i previously corrected it and both are having different IDs but still they both r moving together

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by moving together. They will both act as two spans of text in one line. If one span assumes greater height, this will affect other spans in places where they share one line of text. Are you looking for something more like `display: block`? In that case, what you really want is not a `span` at all, but a `div`, and you shouldn't be inside a `p`.

Answer (score 0):

david's right...hard to tell what's going on...esp. considering the effects of css cascading of styling. is your site available on the net? if so link and i'd be happy to check out the markup and see if i can help

Comment: Sorry its on local server not on internet

Answer (score 0):

adjust your text using padding and margin , give also image display:inline block; .

Comment: Have tried that but the issue is that the both are moving together. I mean if i give margin or padding its being applied on both image as well as on text, although they both are in differnt span tags with different IDs